# GitLab one page per branch

Tags: gitlab

I have a library with multiple Git branches where I would like to generate an HTML documentation for every branch.
Unfortunately, even making sub-directories named like their branch, the pipeline of each branch seems to replace the whole public directory instead of doing additive folder additions.

Is there a way to have each branch contribute to the page without erasing the content contributed by other branches ? Thank you

**EDIT** with the page generation stage:

```
pages:
 image: norionomura/jazzy
 tags:
  - ruby
 script:
  - swift build
  - sourcekitten doc --spm-module Lilas > lilas.json
  - jazzy --clean --min-acl internal --sourcekitten-sourcefile lilas.json --output public
 artifacts:
  paths:
  - public
 only:
  - develop
```

Comment: Can you please provide us a preview of your pipeline ?

Comment: @AndréDS Do you mean the ci file ? I edited my question with the relevant stage.

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending the following to your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME"
  paths:
    - public
```

Adding a `cache` step will tell GitLab to keep the specified `paths` across builds—each new build will see what the previous ones have produced. The `key` element causes GitLab to keep the cache across branches, rather than keep a separate branch for each cache.

Of course this has the side effect that your pipelines will no longer start off with a fresh `public` dir—rather, it will contain whatever the last pipeline left in there. Everything any of your pipelines ever places in `public` will stay there until explicitly deleted or overwritten—you will need to handle that in some way if the set of artifacs changes between builds.

(Haven’t tried this myself yet, but this is how I understand it works.)

Answer (score 0):

Using cache is the right direction, but the solution needs some side features to be fully satisfying.

With below solution, from [GitLab Pages per branch : the no-compromise hack to serve preview pages](https://dev.to/zenika/gitlab-pages-preview-the-no-compromise-hack-to-serve-per-branch-pages-5599) , you can have these features :

- `main` content is exposed on `$CI_PAGES_URL` and the path is configurable with `$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH`
- Per-branch preview content is exposed on `$CI_PAGES_URL/preview`, with a homepage to easily navigate to branches content
- Path to root preview folder is configurable with `$EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH` variable to hide preview content by obfuscation
- Generated pages are associated with environments to take advantage of auto-cleaning on branch deletion
- To avoid disturbing already existing environments, pages environment are placed under a `pages` folder
- If `main` content has not been generated in current cache, or if the cache has been deleted, an error is triggered, to avoid accidental deletion
- Deletion job can be triggered manually with any cache path as input, to clean outdated data
- Code can safely be added to an existing project pipeline without causing trouble with already existing jobs
- The `workflow:rules` can be deleted if you already have your own, or updated to match your flow
- The job must be named `pages` and the artifact must be a `public` folder to be deployed to GitLab Pages (or you can use the [pages:publish](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#pagespublish) keyword)

```yaml
workflow:
  rules: # disable tag pipelines and duplicate MR pipelines
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

variables:
  EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH: preview # subpath to ephemeral branches content for preview, anything will work

pages:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:3.18
  cache:
    key: gitlab-pages
    paths: [public]
  before_script:
    # default available 'tree' app in alpine image does not work as intended
    - apk add tree
    # CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH is defined in rules, different between main branch and ephemeral branches
    - mkdir -p public/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH && ls public/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH/..
    - | # avoid deleting main branch content when cache has been erased
      if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" != "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ] && [ ! -d public/$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH ]; then
        echo -e "\e[91;1m Unable to retrieve $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH generated files from cache ; please regenerate $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH files first\e[0m"
        exit 1
      fi
    - rm -rf public/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH || true # remove last version of current branch
  script:
    - ./generate-my-html.sh --output build-docs || true # insert here your code that generates documentation
    - mv --verbose build-docs public/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH
    - cd public/$EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH
    - tree -d -H '.' -L 1 --noreport --charset utf-8 -T "Versions" -o index.html # generate a root HTML listing all previews for easier access
  environment:
    name: pages/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    action: start
    url: $CI_PAGES_URL/$CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH
    on_stop: pages-clean-preview
  rules:
    # 'main branch' is exposed at GitLab Pages root
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH: "."
    # other (short-lived) branches generation are exposed in 'EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH/branch-name-sanitized' sub path
    - variables:
        CURRENT_CONTENT_PATH: $EPHEMERAL_BRANCHES_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  artifacts:
    paths: [public]
    expire_in: 1h

pages-clean-preview:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:3.18
  cache:
    key: gitlab-pages
    paths: [public]
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none # git files not available after branch deletion
    FOLDER_TO_DELETE: preview/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH # an indirection to allow arbirtraty deletion when launching this job
  script:
    - rm -rf public/$FOLDER_TO_DELETE
  environment:
    name: pages/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    action: stop
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
```